# Wrapper for Python enterprise service provider

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0, python-social-auth, onelogin

**Context:**

I'm researching about how to easily implement SSO for an enterprise on-premise Service Provider to enable SAML and OIDC both. I came across multi-provider wrappers but I wasn't able to find python(tornado) specific ones.

**Research:**

1. The only active one I found is [this](https://github.com/python-social-auth/) but as it’s mostly for social and looks like it doesn’t support saml.
2. [This](https://oauth.net/code/) link mentions some client based python wrappers like sanction, rauth but both doesn't support SAML
3. Apart from wrappers I also looked at dev tools provided by oneLogin for SAML protocol.

   - https://www.onelogin.com/resource-center/saml-toolkits
   - [Python SAML OneLogin - How to support multiple Identity Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684574/python-saml-onelogin-how-to-support-multiple-identity-providers/43944337#43944337)

**Questions:**

1. which are the multi-provider authentication wrapper for python enterprise apps?
2. Are there other options apart from the ones mentioned above to ease the SP development?
3. Could I potentially use a wrapper like python-social-auth for OIDC support and OneLogin devtool for SAML support?

I'm a Product manager and not a dev. I have been researching a lot but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

python-social-auth supports [SAML](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/saml.html) and OIDC. It supports multi-tenancy as well (overriding the default strategy).

I recommend you to use it rather than trying to implement them yourself if you want to save time/money or if your dev team has no much idea about authentication in general.